# How to Populate other fields based on selected dropdowmenuitems in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am having a little challenge on how to achieve something cool. I have a dropdown menu item which is dynamic. the endpoint for dropdown returns other attributes aside the id and value i.e. the name that would be displayed in the dropdownmenuItems. So my challenge right now is this: how can I populate the other textformfields such as the quantity and the uniprice based on the selected dropdown item hence the last updated values for these attributes are in the response json of the dropdown endpoint.

This is the function that returns the dropdown:

```
  Future _scanQR(stockoid, context) async {
    try {

      // This take the barcode Id and parse it to the addItem function to populate the add dialog

      // String qrResult = await BarcodeScanner.scan();
      String qrResult = 'result'; - // this is just to bypass the barcode scan process
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print('$qrResult poi');

      // Make a call to the endpoints that will get the products with a response what contains 
     products attributes

      // print('Anchor ${widget.stockData.anchorOid}, Season  ${widget.stockData.seasonOid}, State ${widget.stockData.stateOid}',);
      _prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      var _productService = ProductService();
      var result = await _productService.getAllProducts(
          widget.stockData.seasonOid,
          _prefs.getInt('providerOid'),
          widget.stockData.anchorOid);

      var products = await json.decode(result.body);
      print("Stock Item Products");
      print(products); - // this results contain more than name and oid other attributes can be seen in the json response below

      products.forEach((product) {
        setState(() {
          _productLists.add(DropdownMenuItem(
            child: Text(product['name']),
            value: product['oid'],
          ));
        });
      });
      setState(() {
        _isLoading = false;
      });


      addItem(qrResult, stockoid, context);
      setState(() {
        result = qrResult;
      });
  
    } on PlatformException catch (ex) {
      if (ex.code == BarcodeScanner.CameraAccessDenied) {
        setState(() {
          result = "Camera permission was denied";
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          result = "Unknown Error $ex";
        });
      }
    } on FormatException {
      setState(() {
        result = "You pressed the back button before scanning anything";
      });
    } catch (ex) {
      setState(() {
        result = "Unknown Error $ex";
      });
    }
  }
```

This is the form field:

```
SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Text(
                        "Add Stock Items",
                        style: style.PoppinsSemiBold(
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: size.convert(context, 20),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    BoxIcon(
                      CustomIcon: Icon(
                        Icons.cancel,
                        color: Colors.blueGrey,
                      ),
                      ontap: () {
                        Navigator.pop(context);
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              SpacebetweenTextField(
                spacing: 20,
              ),
             
              Container(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Container(
                      child: Text(
                        "Enter Date",
                        style: style.PoppinsSemiBold(
                          fontSize: size.convert(context, 14),
                          color: Colors.black,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                    SpacebetweenTextField(
                      spacing: 5,
                    ),
                    DropdownButtonFormField(
                      value: _selectedProduct,
                      items: _productLists,
                      hint: const Text('Select Product'),
                      onChanged: (value) {
                        setState(() {
                          _selectedProduct = value;
                        });
                      },
                    ),
                    SpacebetweenTextField(
                      spacing: 5,
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                      controller: quantity,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.red, //this has no effect
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        hintText: "0.00",
                      ),
                    ),

                      TextFormField(
                      controller: price,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.red, //this has no effect
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        hintText: "NGN 0.00",
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              
              SpacebetweenTextField(
                spacing: 40,
              ),
              Container(
                child: filledButton(
                  leftWidget: Icon(Icons.save, color: Colors.white),
                  txt: "Submit",
                  color1: Color(0xff1b7ec2),
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      _isLoading = true;
                    });
                    _addStock(widget.anchorOid, selectedDate, widget.seasonOid,
                        widget.stateOid, context);

                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ));
```

Response result:

```
Response body
Download
[
  {
    "oid": 2,
    "name": "Certified Seed (Per Kg)",
    "unitPrice": 400,
    "quantity": 1,
    "total": 400,
    "isProduct": true,
    "boldHeader": false
  },
  {
    "oid": 3,
    "name": "Empty Bags",
    "unitPrice": 150,
    "quantity": 1,
    "total": 150,
    "isProduct": true,
    "boldHeader": false
  },
  {
    "oid": 4,
    "name": "Fertilizer UREA",
    "unitPrice": 8000,
    "quantity": 1,
    "total": 8000,
    "isProduct": true,
    "boldHeader": false
  },
  {
    "oid": 5,
    "name": "Fertilzer NPK 15-15-15",
    "unitPrice": 7500,
    "quantity": 1,
    "total": 7500,
    "isProduct": true,
    "boldHeader": false
  }
]
```

Comment: I know what you are asking but don't know how to answer it. It's not aske in minimal format

Comment: @nitishk72 ok Please how can I go about it? Any idea will greatly help sir.

Comment: Can you help me our @huzaifa-ahmed

Comment: Do you have any idea @lee3